# Servlet not updating value in database

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to create a basic password reset system. I'm creating an unique token for each user, storing in database and retrieving that token value in url like: http://localhost:8080/login/reset-password.jsp?token=0d1eaa1a-869c-4f40-8437-a3cdaeddf497

The problem here is that I'm trying to update the password in the database but the value isn't updated. It displays that the password is changed, but nothing happens in database. Please help.

Here's my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String token = request.getParameter("token");



                ForgotPasswordHandler.UpdatePassword(password, token);

                String message = "Password changed!";
                request.setAttribute("message", message);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("reset-password.jsp?token=" + token).forward(request, response);   



    }
```

Here's my method in class ForgotPasswordHandler.java:

```
public static void UpdatePassword(String password, String token) {

            try
              {

              if (con == null){
                 System.out.println("Failed connection");

              }else{

                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                  "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE reset_token = ?");

                ps.setString(1,password);
                ps.setString(2,token);

                ps.executeUpdate();

                ps.close();


              }}
            catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(System.out);    
              }

            }
```

Comment: does `password` and `token`  have required value ?

Comment: Can you please run the below query and share the result? what is reset_token? reset_token is constant per user?

SELECT * FROM USER WHERE reset_token='0d1eaa1a-869c-4f40-8437-a3cdaeddf497';

Comment: In my answer below, I made the assumption that you could find a user by the reset token. As @Govind asks above, I think you need to verify that the reset_token is set correctly for the user.

Comment: @Govind so I tried that and actually it worked perfectly. So the problem is that I'm not being able to request the value from URL

Answer (score 0):

Your connection may have autoCommit turned off. If that is the problem you can fix it with code like this:

```
   if (!con.getAutoCommit()) {
      con.commit();
   }
```

One other thing to note is that if the call to ps.executeUpdate() fails, the prepared statement will not be cleaned up. To avoid that problem move the close to the finally block. Here is what the full code would look like:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try
{
    if (con == null){
        System.out.println("Failed connection");
    } else {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE reset_token = ?");

        ps.setString(1,password);
        ps.setString(2,token);

        ps.executeUpdate();   

       if (!con.getAutoCommit()) {
          con.commit();
       }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);    
} 
finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried both solutions. But when I move close to finally block it just gives me java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Nayana - I edited the post to include the full method. I also realized that I messed up and you need to commit if autoCommit is not set. When debugging - put a breakpoint on the check for autoCommit and see if you even enter into that block.

Comment: It works perfectly when I insert the token value directly into the sql query on reset_token. I think I'm not being able to request the parameter from the url but I don't understand why